# How to change background color for Dialog in Angular Material (Version 16)

Tags: css, angular, typescript, sass, angular-material

I've been trying to change the background color for my Angular Material Dialog by using the `panelClass` property of the `MatDialogConfig`.

However, it seems like it's half-working. I'm trying to set the background color to red (for testing purposes) and when you open the dialog, I can see the red panel is actually appearing before it gets covered by the actual Dialog with a white background. Please look at the attached image to see what I mean.

***As soon as Dialog opens, the red background is applied***
[image: As soon as Dialog opens, the red background is applied]

***Within a split second, the actual form covers the red background***
[image: Within a split second, the actual form covers the red background]

This is not what I'm trying to achieve. I'm trying to make the ACTUAL FORM'S background color to be red. So my question is, how do I change the background color correctly? Here are the code I've got.

Thanks

**Method that opens the form**

```
public openCreateDialog(): void {

    const row = new Product();

    const dislogConfig = new MatDialogConfig();
    dislogConfig.data = row;
    dislogConfig.panelClass = 'test';


    const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(DialogComponent, dislogConfig);

    dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(result => {
      this.getPagedProduct(this.currentPageNum);
    })

  }
```

**Dialog HTML**

```
<h1 mat-dialog-title>Dialog with elements</h1>
<div mat-dialog-content>This dialog showcases the title, close, content and actions elements.</div>
<div mat-dialog-actions>
  <button mat-button mat-dialog-close>Close</button>
</div>
```

**styles.scss**

```
@use '@angular/material' as mat;

@use 'theme/baseTheme' as base;


html,
body {
    height: 100%;
}

 .theme-primary {
        background-color: mat.get-color-from-palette(base.$s-brand-primary, 500);
}
 

.theme-pink {
    background-color: mat.get-color-from-palette(base.$s-brand-accent, 500);
}

.test > mat-dialog-container {
    background-color: red;
}

.mat-mdc-row:hover .mat-mdc-cell {
    background-color: #fafafa;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

two solution:

solution one:

```
<div style="background-color: red;">
  <h1 mat-dialog-title>Dialog with elements</h1>
  <div mat-dialog-content>This dialog showcases the title, close, content and actions elements.</div>
  <div mat-dialog-actions>
  <button mat-button mat-dialog-close>Close</button>
</div>
```

solution two:

```
.mdc-dialog__surface::before {
  background-color: red;
 }
```